# Is it possible to show "Clipboard History view/dialog" programmatically in UWP

Tags: uwp, clipboard

in windows 10 its possible to show Clipboard history using (Windows logo + V) shortcut.

Is it possible to trigger this view programmatically in C# UWP?

Comment: I nevers used it but what does [Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.gethistoryitemsasync?view=winrt-18362) returns?

Comment: It returns history item (as mentioned in API description), 
But I need to show Systems "Clipboard History" view (same as Windows logo + V).

Comment: There is no guarantee that every UWP system will have a Clipboard History viewer built-in with the Win-V hotkey. (For example, I wouldn't be surprised if it were missing from Hub and Xbox.) You should display the history items in your app, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: right @RaymondChen , I missed this point.

Answer (score 0):

> **I need to show Systems "Clipboard History" view**

A possible way is that you could inject virtual input using [InputInjector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector?view=winrt-18362). Create an InputInjector object and you could inject Windows keypress and V keypress in code so that you could trigger the system Clipboard view.

You could try the following code. I've tested this and it works in my side.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

        //press the windows key
        var info = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
        info.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.LeftWindows;
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });


        //Press the v key
        var info2 = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
        info2.VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.V;
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info2 });



        //release the  Windows key
        info.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });


        // release the V key
        info2.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });

    }
```

There is one thing needs to be remembered is that using InputInjector Class requires `inputInjectionBrokered` [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities).

Comment: Thanks for answer but But I can not use "Restricted Capability".

Comment: If not using the restricted capability to inject virtual input in UWP apps, there is no other way to trigger the system view of Clipboard.